# Is DI(dependency injection) necessary for mocking dependencies in golang?

Tags: unit-testing, go, dependency-injection

When I try to unit test a function as below, where `extern_pkg` is an external package to be mocked:

```golang
import "extern_pkg"

func MyFunc() {
  ...
  extern_pkg.F()
}

func main() {
  MyFunc()
}
```

I read a few blogs, and they all seem to achieve this by modifying prod code with dependency injection. For example, as below:

```golang
type exter interface {
  F()
}

func MyFunc(e exter) {
  ...
  e.F()
}

type extpkg struct{}

func (extpkg) F() {extern_pkg.F()}

func main() {
  epkg := extpkg{}
  MyFunc(epkg)
}
```

Then in test code, create a mock object that satisfies `exter` interface, and pass to `MyFunc` as parameter.

My question is:

1. If the `MyFunc` function contains many external packages to mock, do I need to DI each one as function parameters? Is it also true for any global variables the function depends on?

```golang
var global_var

func MyFunc() {
  ...
  extern_pkg1.F()
  ...
  extern_pkg2.G()
  ...
  extern_pkg3.H()
  ...
  global_var
}
```

2. Is there way to avoid modifying prod code?

Thanks!

Comment: It is a matter of clean design as the problem code is currently tightly coupled to 3rd party external dependencies

Comment: You can't mock or inject a package, that's not how packages work. You can mock or inject types and functions, but not packages - there is no "package value" you could pass.

Comment: @Adrian Okay, then what my intent was to mock the types and functions in a package. Any ideas for my questions?

Comment: To Q1: yes, you need to DI each one. If you have one function with many dependencies, that's a code smell indicating it should be refactored. To Q2: unclear what you're asking. If your prod code isn't testable as-is, then you'll have to modify it to test it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try use vars of func types and inject them. It is easier, lesser code and interfaces are not needed. See [godif](https://github.com/untillpro/godif)